# Cambiar el Setting del Preview

Tags: android-studio

Hola disculpame que te moleste con esta consulta. No logro visualizar el celular como imagen del View "Preview" a la hora de programa el Layout.

Según me han dicho eso venía en versiones anteriores, lo que me hizo dudar. Pienso que por medio del Setting tendría que poder escoger esta posibilidad, pero no logro dar con la Opción que permita hacerlo.

Muchas gracias por cualquier comentario que me ayude a realizar este cambio.

[image: Imagen actual]

Answer (score 1):

Ve a la pestaña `Design` donde puedes cambiar el layout por la vista de diseño.

Una diferencia notable es que la imagen del celular/móvil que contiene el layout ya no se visualiza, la razón es evitar espacio no necesario ya que se agrego la vista del [**ConstraintLayout**](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]